# Aparece el siguiente error en mi codigo: expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++

*El codigo es el siguiente:*

```
class Cilindro{
private:
   double radio;
   double altura;
public:
    Cilindro(double radio, double altura){
        this -> altura = altura;
        this -> radio = radio;
    }
    
    Circulo base = Circulo(radio);
    
    void Volumen(){
        double volumen;
        volumen = altura * (base.Area());
        cout << volumen;
    }

    

    void Superficie(){
        double superficie;
        superficie = 2 * (cir.Area()+ altura ) * cir.Perimetro();
        cout << superficie;
    }

};
```

Cuando declaro el objeto en la clase cilindro no sé como aplicar la formula y que se multiplique o hacer operaciones con las funciones que llamo con el objeto.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Cilindro {
public:
    Circulo base = Circulo(radio);
};
```

Esa declaración está fuera de lugar. Fíjate que el objeto `base` necesita, para su inicialización, una variable llamada `radio` que, ¿dónde se encuentra esa variable? En ese contexto no existe o, de existir, será una variable global ... no creo que sea esa tu intención:

```
class Cilindro {
private:
   double radio;
   double altura;
public:
    Cilindro(double radio, double altura)
        : base{radio}
    {
        this -> altura = altura;
        this -> radio = radio;
    }
    
    Circulo base;
```

De esta forma usas el constructor para inicialiar el objeto miembro `base`. La parte que se encuentra entre los dos puntos y la llave de apertura de la función se puede usar única y exclusivamente para invocar a constructores de variables miembro.

También podrías hacerlo así:

```
class Cilindro {
private:
   double radio;
   double altura;
public:
    Cilindro(double radio, double altura)
    {
        this -> altura = altura;
        this -> radio = radio;
        base = Circulo(radio);
    }
    
    Circulo base;
```

Pero entonces el programa haría lo siguiente:

1. Inicializaría `base` invocando al constructor por defecto de `Circulo`
2. Se crea un objeto temporal de tipo `Circulo` se invoca su constructor `Circulo(double)`
3. Se copia el estado del objeto temporal en `base`
4. Se elimina el objeto temporal

También estás haciendo uso de variables desconocidas en `Superficie()`:

```
void Superficie(){
    double superficie;
    superficie = 2 * (cir.Area()+ altura ) * cir.Perimetro();
    cout << superficie;
}
```

¿Dónde has declarado `cir`? Si lo has hecho no aparece en el código del ejemplo. Quizás aquí simplemente debas cambiar `cir` por `base`.

Fíjate también que puedes declarar e inicializar en la misma línea. Es por tanto preferible esto:

```
    double volumen = altura * (base.Area());
```

a esto

```
    double volumen;
    volumen = altura * (base.Area());
```

La razón es que así la variable `volumen` puede ser utilizada sin preocupaciones desde el mismo momento en el que está declarada. Retrasar las inicializaciones provoca problemas cuando, por despiste, desconocimiento, prisas, ... se acaba usando la variable antes de estar correctamente inicializada.

Como última recomendación, saca esos `cout` de las funciones. Deberías limitar la cantidad de responsabilidades diferentes que tienen tus funciones. Funciones con muchas responsabilidades acaban siendo complicadas de manejar, de depurar y de testear.

En tu caso, la función `Volumen` tiene dos responsabilidades:

- Calcular el volumen del cilindro
- Mostrar el resultado por pantalla

Ahora supongamos que hace falta que el volumen se saque también por la impresora, ¿qué hacemos ahora? ¿Creamos una segunda función que haga el mismo cálculo? ¿Complicamos la función para elegir, en base al valor de ciertas variables, por dónde sacamos ese valor?

Estos problemas se resuelven más facilmente si las funciones se limitan a una única responsabilidad:

```
class Cilindro
{
    double Volumen()
    {
        return altura * base.Area();
    }
};

void imprimirPorPantallaElVolumen(Cilindro cilindro)
{ std::cout << cilindro.Volumen(); }

void SacarPorImpresoraElVolumen(Cilindro cilindro)
{
    // ...
}

void GuardarVolumenEnArchivo(Cilindro cilindro, std::ofstream & archivo)
{
    // ...
}
```